# How are constitutive enzymes regulated?

Tags: endocrinology, enzymes, gene-regulation

I found that inducible enzymes can be regulated by many ways, but
I cannot find how constitutive enzymes are regulated...

Answer (score 1):

A constitutive or "housekeeping" enzyme is usually [defined](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01289.html) as an enzyme whose expression level (amount of protein) is always constant, independent of any environmental factors. Hence, regulation of constitutive enzymes must be post-translational, for example allosteric regulation of the enzymatic activity by substrates or products.

Note that constitutive enzymes is mostly a theoretical concept. There are probably no enzymes whose expression is completely unaffected by *any* environmental factor.

Comment: why do you say constitutive enzymes is mostly a theoretical concept?

Comment: Because I have yet to see an enzyme whose expression is not regulated at the transcriptional/translational level in *some* experimental condition. An enzyme's protein level might be constant in some particular experiment, but who's to say what will happen in another setting. It's the same problem as with "housekeeping genes" in RT-PCR.